# ValueError: shapes (3,) and (4,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 4

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

inputs = [1, 2, 3, 2.5]
weights = [
    [0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
    [0.5 -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
    [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]

biases = [2, 3, 0.5]

output = np.dot(weights, inputs) + biases
print(output)
```

I'm very new to numpy, and wrote a dot product using the following "inputs" vector, "weights" matrix, and "biases" vector. The output gives me a shape error:

> ValueError: shapes (3,) and (4,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 4

Comment: Were you expecting the (3,) shape?  Did you `print(weights.shape)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out your problem, it is a common problem of forgetting a comma and "fusing together" array elements, here I added `np.array` to your code:

```
import numpy as np

inputs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2.5])
weights = np.array([
    [0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
    [0.5 -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
    [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]
    ])

biases = [2, 3, 0.5]


output = np.dot(weights, inputs) + biases
print(output)
```

Now I get the deprecation warning:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  weights = np.array([
```

You must add the comma `,` to separate the items here:

```
[0.5 -0.91, 0.26, -0.5], ->     [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
```

Final code:

```
import numpy as np

inputs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2.5])
weights = np.array([
    [0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
    [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
    [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]
    ])

biases = [2, 3, 0.5]


output = np.dot(weights, inputs) + biases
print(output)
```

Comment: Make sure to read the full warning + error messages that you get